# Link Kafka and HDFS with docker containers

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, hdfs, apache-kafka-connect

**Hello Guys, I'm trying to connect Kafka and HDFS with Kafka Connect, but I still face an issue that I can't rid of it.**

**I'm using this example: https://clubhouse.io/developer-how-to/how-to-set-up-a-hadoop-cluster-in-docker/**

**I start the HDFS first with: docker-compose up -d**

**Then I launch the zookeeper kafka and mysql with images from debezium website.
https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/1.0/tutorial.html**

*docker run -it --rm --name zookeeper --network docker-hadoop-master_default -p 2181:2181 -p 2888:2888 -p 3888:3888 debezium/zookeeper:1.0*

*docker run -it --rm --name kafka --network docker-hadoop-master_default -e ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper -p 9092:9092 --link zookeeper:zookeeper debezium/kafka:1.0*

*docker run -it --rm --name mysql --network docker-hadoop-master_default -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium -e MYSQL_USER=mysqluser -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw debezium                    /example-mysql:1.0*

**I use the network on these runs because when I tried to change the network from HDFS on docker-compose.yml the resource manager shutdown and no matter how I couldn't find how I could raise up again and make him stable.** 
**So added directly on these containers zookeeper kafka and mysql.**

**Then, this is the most tricky part, the Kafka Connect, I used the same network to on this case which makes sense.**

*docker run -it --rm --name connect --network docker-hadoop-master_default -p 8083:8083 -e GROUP_ID=1 -e CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs -e OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets -e STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses -e BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS="172.18.0.10:9092" -e CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://172.18.0.2:9000 --link namenode:namenode --link zookeeper:zookeeper --link mysql:mysql debezium/connect:1.0*

**To link the source (Mysql) to Kafka I uses the connector from the debezium tutorial, the one below.**

*curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{ "name": "inventory-connector", "config": { "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector", "tasks.max": "1", "database.hostname": "mysql", "database.port": "3306", "database.user": "debezium", "database.password": "dbz", "database.server.id": "184054", "database.server.name": "dbserver1", "database.whitelist": "inventory", "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "kafka:9092", "database.history.kafka.topic": "dbhistory.inventory" } }'*

**I tested if Kafka receives any event from the source and works fine.**

**After setting this, I moved to the installation of the plugin, which I downloaded from the confluent web site and pasted on my local machine Linux, then I installed the Confluent-Hub, and after that the plugin on my local machine. Then I created the user kafka and change all the content from the plugin directory into kafka:kafka.**

**After all this I used docker cp  :/kafka/connect to copy to Kafka Connect.**

**Then check if it is there and then restart the Kafka Connect to install it.**

**We can use this to check if is installed:** *curl -i -X GET -H "Accept:application/json" localhost:8083/connector-plugins*

**You need to see somewhere this:** *[{"class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.4.0"},…*

After this step I believe is where my problem resides:
*curl -i -X POST -H "Accept:application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors/ -d '{"name":"hdfs-sink","config":{"connector.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector","tasks.max":1,"topics":"dbserver1,dbserver1.inventory.products,dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand,dbserver1.inventory.customers,dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom,dbserver1.inventory.addresses","hdfs.url":"hdfs://**172.18.0.2:9000**","flush.size":3,"logs.dir":"logs","topics.dir":"kafka","format.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat","partitioner.class":"io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner","partition.field.name":"day"}}'*

**I have no idea how to convince Kafka Connect that I want a specific IP address from the namenode, he just keeps my trowing messages that found a different IP when the expected is hdfs://namenode:9000**

**Also adding this** *-e CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://172.18.0.2:9000* **to the docker run our setting it inside the Kafka Connect, when I POST the Curl of hdfs-sink he trowing me the message below.**

**Log from Kafka Connect:**

```
2020-01-21 15:22:09,597 INFO   ||  Creating connector hdfs-sink of type io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,597 INFO   ||  Instantiated connector hdfs-sink with version 5.4.0 of type class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,598 INFO   ||  HdfsSinkConnectorConfig values:
        avro.codec = null
        connect.hdfs.keytab =
        connect.hdfs.principal =
        connect.meta.data = true
        enhanced.avro.schema.support = false
        filename.offset.zero.pad.width = 10
        flush.size = 3
        format.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
        hadoop.conf.dir =
        hadoop.home =
        hdfs.authentication.kerberos = false
        hdfs.namenode.principal =
        hdfs.url = hdfs://172.18.0.2:9000
        kerberos.ticket.renew.period.ms = 3600000
        logs.dir = logs
        retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        rotate.interval.ms = -1
        rotate.schedule.interval.ms = -1
        schema.cache.size = 1000
        schema.compatibility = NONE
        shutdown.timeout.ms = 3000
   [io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,599 INFO   ||  StorageCommonConfig values:
        directory.delim = /
        file.delim = +
        storage.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage
        store.url = null
        topics.dir = kafka
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.common.StorageCommonConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,599 INFO   ||  HiveConfig values:
        hive.conf.dir =
        hive.database = default
        hive.home =
        hive.integration = false
        hive.metastore.uris =
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.HiveConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,600 INFO   ||  PartitionerConfig values:
        locale =
        partition.duration.ms = -1
        partition.field.name = [day]
        partitioner.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
        path.format =
        timestamp.extractor = Wallclock
        timestamp.field = timestamp
        timezone =
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,601 INFO   ||  Finished creating connector hdfs-sink   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,601 INFO   ||  SinkConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        topics = [dbserver1, dbserver1.inventory.products, dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand, dbserver1.inventory.customers, dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom, dbserver1.inventory.addresses]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,602 INFO   ||  EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        topics = [dbserver1, dbserver1.inventory.products, dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand, dbserver1.inventory.customers, dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom, dbserver1.inventory.addresses]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,604 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Starting task hdfs-sink-0   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,605 INFO   ||  Creating task hdfs-sink-0   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,606 INFO   ||  ConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,607 INFO   ||  EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,608 INFO   ||  TaskConfig values:
        task.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TaskConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,608 INFO   ||  Instantiated task hdfs-sink-0 with version 5.4.0 of type io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,609 INFO   ||  JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = key
        decimal.format = BASE64
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = true
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,610 INFO   ||  Set up the key converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter for task hdfs-sink-0 using the worker config   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,610 INFO   ||  JsonConverterConfig values:
        converter.type = value
        decimal.format = BASE64
        schemas.cache.size = 1000
        schemas.enable = true
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverterConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,611 INFO   ||  Set up the value converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter for task hdfs-sink-0 using the worker config   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,611 INFO   ||  Set up the header converter class org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.SimpleHeaderConverter for task hdfs-sink-0 using the worker config   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,613 INFO   ||  Initializing: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.TransformationChain{}   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.Worker]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,614 INFO   ||  SinkConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        topics = [dbserver1, dbserver1.inventory.products, dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand, dbserver1.inventory.customers, dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom, dbserver1.inventory.addresses]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.SinkConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,618 INFO   ||  EnrichedConnectorConfig values:
        config.action.reload = restart
        connector.class = io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector
        errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable = false
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name =
        errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor = 3
        errors.log.enable = false
        errors.log.include.messages = false
        errors.retry.delay.max.ms = 60000
        errors.retry.timeout = 0
        errors.tolerance = none
        header.converter = null
        key.converter = null
        name = hdfs-sink
        tasks.max = 1
        topics = [dbserver1, dbserver1.inventory.products, dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand, dbserver1.inventory.customers, dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom, dbserver1.inventory.addresses]
        topics.regex =
        transforms = []
        value.converter = null
   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.ConnectorConfig$EnrichedConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,622 INFO   ||  ConsumerConfig values:
        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = earliest
        bootstrap.servers = [172.18.0.10:9092]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = default
        client.id = connector-consumer-hdfs-sink-0
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = connect-hdfs-sink
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,653 INFO   ||  Kafka version: 2.4.0   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,653 INFO   ||  Kafka commitId: 77a89fcf8d7fa018   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,654 INFO   ||  Kafka startTimeMs: 1579620129652   [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,659 INFO   ||  [Worker clientId=connect-1, groupId=1] Finished starting connectors and tasks   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.distributed.DistributedHerder]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,677 INFO   ||  [Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-hdfs-sink-0, groupId=connect-hdfs-sink] Subscribed to topic(s): dbserver1, dbserver1.inventory.products, dbserver1.inventory.products_on_hand, dbserver1.inventory.customers, dbserver1.inventory.orders, dbserver1.inventory.geom, dbserver1.inventory.addresses   [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,678 INFO   ||  HdfsSinkConnectorConfig values:
        avro.codec = null
        connect.hdfs.keytab =
        connect.hdfs.principal =
        connect.meta.data = true
        enhanced.avro.schema.support = false
        filename.offset.zero.pad.width = 10
        flush.size = 3
        format.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.parquet.ParquetFormat
        hadoop.conf.dir =
        hadoop.home =
        hdfs.authentication.kerberos = false
        hdfs.namenode.principal =
        hdfs.url = hdfs://172.18.0.2:9000
        kerberos.ticket.renew.period.ms = 3600000
        logs.dir = logs
        retry.backoff.ms = 5000
        rotate.interval.ms = -1
        rotate.schedule.interval.ms = -1
        schema.cache.size = 1000
        schema.compatibility = NONE
        shutdown.timeout.ms = 3000
   [io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnectorConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,679 INFO   ||  StorageCommonConfig values:
        directory.delim = /
        file.delim = +
        storage.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage
        store.url = null
        topics.dir = kafka
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.common.StorageCommonConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,679 INFO   ||  HiveConfig values:
        hive.conf.dir =
        hive.database = default
        hive.home =
        hive.integration = false
        hive.metastore.uris =
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.hive.HiveConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,680 INFO   ||  PartitionerConfig values:
        locale =
        partition.duration.ms = -1
        partition.field.name = [day]
        partitioner.class = class io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.DefaultPartitioner
        path.format =
        timestamp.extractor = Wallclock
        timestamp.field = timestamp
        timezone =
   [io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.PartitionerConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,681 INFO   ||  AvroDataConfig values:
        connect.meta.data = true
        enhanced.avro.schema.support = false
        schemas.cache.config = 1000
   [io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroDataConfig]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,681 INFO   ||  Hadoop configuration directory    [io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter]
2020-01-21 15:22:09,757 ERROR  ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 36: hdfs://namenode.docker-hadoop-master_default:9000
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getCanonicalUri(NetUtils.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.canonicalizeUri(DistributedFileSystem.java:1577)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getCanonicalUri(FileSystem.java:235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.checkPath(FileSystem.java:623)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getPathName(DistributedFileSystem.java:194)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.access$000(DistributedFileSystem.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem$22.doCall(DistributedFileSystem.java:1301)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystemLinkResolver.resolve(FileSystemLinkResolver.java:81)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.getFileStatus(DistributedFileSystem.java:1317)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.exists(FileSystem.java:1426)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.storage.HdfsStorage.exists(HdfsStorage.java:149)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.createDir(DataWriter.java:548)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:222)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.DataWriter.<init>(DataWriter.java:102)
        at io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkTask.start(HdfsSinkTask.java:84)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:189)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in hostname at index 36: hdfs://namenode.docker-hadoop-master_default:9000
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2913)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHostname(URI.java:3448)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseServer(URI.java:3297)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseAuthority(URI.java:3216)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3158)
        at java.base/java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3114)
        at java.base/java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:685)
        at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.getCanonicalUri(NetUtils.java:272)
        ... 24 more
2020-01-21 15:22:09,759 ERROR  ||  WorkerSinkTask{id=hdfs-sink-0} Task is being killed and will not recover until manually restarted   [org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask]
```

IP addresses:
Namenode: 172.18.0.2
Kafka:172.18.0.10

I believe this could be something related to the network.

The error is more below, hope you guys help me. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're using docker-compse, why are you also doing `docker run`?

Comment: @cricket_007 the docker-compose file that i have is one from the example that I have explained above, the docker runs is from the debezium tutorial, I'm new at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Docker compose adds an underscore and the directory where you ran the command underscore is not allowed in a hostname. Hadoop prefers hostnames by default in the `hdfs-site.xml` config file.

> I have no idea how to convince Kafka Connect that I want a specific IP address from the namenode, he just keeps my trowing messages that found a different IP when the expected is hdfs://namenode:9000

Ideally, you wouldn't use an IP within Docker anyway, you would use the service name and exposed port.

For the HDFS Connector, you also need to define 1) `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` env-var 2) mount your XML configs as a volume for remote clients such as Connect to interact with the Hadoop cluster and 3) define `hadoop.conf.dir` in connector property.